# 100% CPU use when physics paused and GUI closed

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I pause physics from GUI, close the GUI, then Gazebo still takes 100% of one core.
Experiencing this with Gazebo 1.2.5 (came with ROS Groovy), have not tried with other versions.

Why? Any way to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1327/100%-cpu-use-when-physics-paused-and-gui-closed/) by [r0nald](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/138/r0nald/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This was reported as [gazebo issue #102](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/102), solved by [pull request #48](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/48) and is fixed in gazebo 1.3.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on 2015-04-08**:
This was not fixed. It's happening to me in Gazebo 4.1.1.

**Comment by [AbdealiJK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1250/abdealijk/) on 2015-12-21**:
I get this in gazebo 2.2.3 also. Any fix for it ?